# How to play AAX audio books from Audible?

Tags: arch-linux, vlc, drm

I have bought some audio books at Audible. The default .aa files play fine in VLC, but the quality is pretty bad - there's a constant background hum during any speech. Their [enhanced quality audio files](https://www.audible.co.uk/lib) open in VLC, which displays the frontispiece, chapter number, and progress indicator, but **there is no sound.** Is it possible to fix this (Linux and open source software being the two parameters I care about)?

The latest VLC (2.2.4) displays the following codec information for an .aax file:

- Stream 0

  - Type: Audio
  - Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (aavd)
  - Language: English
  - Sample rate: 44100 Hz
  - Bits per sample: 16
  - Bitrate: 1411 kb/s
- Stream 1

  - Type: Subtitle
  - Codec: tx3g
  - Language: English

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [audible-activator](https://github.com/inAudible-NG/audible-activator) and [AAXtoMP3](https://github.com/KrumpetPirate/AAXtoMP3) worked. With a few [tweaks](https://github.com/l0b0/AAXtoMP3), AAXtoMP3 converts to FLAC as well.

Comment: works for me with debian jessie (following the requirements of the linked articles/software, btw: using ffmpeg from jessie-backports and libmp3lame-dev from apt)

Comment: I used this method to convert an audiobook to MP3 for listening to in the car, but the quality was quite low. Not sure if that is just the quality of the AAX file or the conversion process.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the cross-platform [OpenAudible](https://github.com/openaudible/openaudible). You can connect to your Audible account, manage/download your Audible audiobooks, and convert to mp3.

Comment: Very interesting! I've stopped using Audible in the meantime, but this may be an option.

Comment: OpenAudible is not free software and you need  to buy a licence to convert from aax to other formats.

Comment: @AlpiMurányi Correct, unfortunately OpenAudible is no longer free nor open source, though it previously was when this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Audible file using "Audio Quality: Format 4" which will be saved with the extension .aa then after downloading open the file in VLC (version tested/used 3.0.6 Vetinari).  I'm using RebornOS (Arch Distro).  I was able to play the file, as well as use the File Convert within VLC to save it as an .mp3.  Audio quality is very good.

Comment: The question is not about the .aa files, but rather .aax.

Comment: And unfortunately, aa files have been discontinued.